# How to find if a Site Collection is deleted in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection

I'm using `Tenant.GetDeletedSiteProperties` method to find deleted Site Collections. Is there any other way to find if a Site Collection is deleted in SharePoint Online (without using SharePoint Online Management Shell)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the UI, from SharePoint Admin Center. Navigate to your Admin center and on the ribbon, you should see the recycle bin where you can find any deleted site collections.

Answer (score -1):

**--------EXAMPLE 1--------**

```
Get-SPODeletedSite -Identity http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing
```

This example returns the properties for the deleted site collection `http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing` that is in the Recycle Bin.

**--------EXAMPLE 2--------**

```
Get-SPODeletedSite -IncludePersonalSite
```

This example returns all of the properties for the deleted sites, including Personal Sites, that are in the Recycle Bin.

**--------EXAMPLE 3--------**

```
Get-SPODeletedSite - IncludeOnlyPersonalSite
```

This example returns all of the properties for only the Personal sites, that are in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: (without using SharePoint Online Management Shell)?

Comment: I needed without using online Mgmt shell, anyways thanks @Hardik